# Loading full.js doesn't seem to work in Chrome

Tags: support, javascript, google-chrome

The Chrome Dev tools say:

> Failed to load resource

When I go to http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js?v=c492477fd55e Chrome says (translated from Dutch):

> Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED): Unknown error

Just in case (and because debuggers love pictures): http://screencast.com/t/xw86W7YBtm

Loading the script in Firefox seems to work. Is the script encoded unreliably? What do I have to do to get it working again?

Lose the hightech encoding and compression and give me back SO Javascript functionality =)

**edit**
Huh and now I'm a little bit worried. [From Jeff Atwood's blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/06/suspension-ban-or-hellban.html):

> An errorbanned user has errors inserted at random into pages they visit. You might consider this a more severe extension of slowbanning – instead of pages loading slowly, they might not load at all, return cryptic HTTP errors, return the wrong page altogether, **fail to load key dependencies like JavaScript and images and CSS**, and so forth. I'm sure your devious little brains can imagine dozens of ways things could go "wrong" for an errorbanned user. This one is a bit more esoteric, but it isn't theoretical; an existing implementation exists in the form of the Drupal Misery module.

Comment: Just FYI, SE doesn't practice hellbanning.

Comment: Well, that's good to know at least. In that case there's actually something wrong with the JS. Just now, I could see that I had 1 StackExchange 'message' (the red 1 in the top left corner) but I couldn't open the messagebox =(

Comment: BTW: the JS on meta works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clearing your cache.

Chrome since version 11 has some really severe caching bugs that we've seen (and duplicated on the dev team).

Comment: It worked without clearing the cache...