# Navbar CSS not loading on stackexchange.com - net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

Tags: bug, top-bar, stackexchange.com, google-chrome

What happened to the navbar on http://stackexchange.com?

[image]

Appears to be caused by this error:

> net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED http://cdn.sstatic.net/skins/topbar/topbar.css

Browser: Chrome 47.0.2526.106 (no add-ons)

Comment: Refresh the page?

Comment: @Doorknob i already tried many times but it wont change

Comment: @NBOT Any information on your browser would be nice for reproducibility.

Comment: @scriptHero There is no anything else, im running chrome 47 withouth any add-ons.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+I to open dev tools, flip to the network tab, reload, see what isn't loading.

Comment: @Shog9 found problem, Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED http://cdn.sstatic.net/skins/topbar/topbar.css

Comment: what do you see when you visit that link directly?

Comment: Note that it seems to be working for me, Safari on iOS

Comment: @Shog9 Web page not available.

Comment: Works fine on mozilla.

Comment: Try a few hard refreshes & see if that fixes it; otherwise, let's wait & see if anyone else is encountering this.

Comment: @Shog9 I restarted chrome and refreshed many times but i got same error, i cant even see that .css file.

Comment: Yeah, this is kinda bizarre; need someone experienced in CDN debugging to assist.

Comment: I got same error on chat.stackoverflow.com, chat.meta.stackexchange.com, works fine on meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: From [SuperUser entry for this particular error](http://superuser.com/questions/172951/chrome-error-330-neterr-content-decoding-failed), it seems to be a problem from the server (not sure it's SE or CDN server), but might as well as the browser. Also, [the same ancient issue reported on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94772/loading-full-js-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-chrome)

Comment: Well, you are a bot. Bots don't need CSS, and SE is smart enough to know that. Kudos to SE! :D